# Prompt for value, then copy but add text (Pt 2)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

For Part 1 of my request, the following code helped me populate cells `G2:G10`

Link to Part 1: [Prompt for value, then copy but add text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614705/)

```
Sub Set_Tag()

Dim TagName As String
Dim x As Long, TagNum As Long, i As Long, k As Long

TagName = InputBox("What is the product tag name? Ex. Apple", "Tag Name")
TagNum = InputBox("What is the first product tag #?", "1st Tag #")

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("J:J"), " ")

With ActiveSheet.Range("G2")
    For i = 1 To x Step 3
        .Item(i + 0) = TagName & "_" & TagNum + k
        .Item(i + 1) = TagName & "_" & TagNum + k & "_T"
        .Item(i + 2) = TagName & "_" & TagNum + k & "_NE"
        k = k + 10
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

For Part 2, I need the macro to continue populating values in Column G with different values.  The starting cell would be at row `x+2`, or `G11` in the above example.  I have code that works for what I need, the only thing is `G11` is hardcoded as the starting cell.  I'd like to replace that with something more logical, as it may not be the starting cell for all files.

```
Sub Set_Tag2()

Dim TagName As String
Dim x As Long, TagNum2 As Long, i As Long, k As Long

TagName = InputBox("What is the product tag name? Ex. Apple", "Tag Name")
TagNum2 = InputBox("What is the second PDW tag #?", "2nd Tag #")

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("J:J"), " ")

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("G11")
    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
        .Item(i + 0) = TagName & "_RED_" & TagNum2 + k
        k = k + 10
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

So if the user inputs `Apple` as TagName and `1060` as TagNum2, the remaining cells would populate as follows:

```
Apple_RED_1060
Apple_RED_1070
Apple_RED_1080
```

...continued until `LastRow`. Can someone help me replace `With ActiveSheet.Range("G11")` with something more logical and dynamic?

Comment: It's counting the # of rows that have a space in them.

Comment: When you say "I need the second part of the macro to populate the remaining cells in Column G as follows", what are the remaining cells in G to populate (i.e. when should the second loop stop)

Comment: If I use the code `Cells(x + 2, "G").Select`, this is the starting cell for `Apple_RED_1060`.  Likewise if I use `Cells(LastRow, "G").Select`, that will give me the last row in column G for the for loop

Comment: Sorry, I think the link for Part 1 might explain a bit more about how this macro started.  I don't know why `k` isn't set in the original macro, but I think it's `0` if nothing is declared

Comment: Still not sure I understand, your original question (i.e. Part 1) has two parts and they are both resolved by the answer given by @ExcelHero ...?

Comment: @Jaycal can you refresh the original post?  I removed Part 2 so ExcelHero only answers Part 1.  Part 1 fills up the first `x` number of rows as follows:
`Apple_100`
`Apple_100_T`
`Apple_100_NE`
`Apple_110`
`Apple_110_T`
`Apple_110_NE`
`Apple_120`
`Apple_120_T`
`Apple_120_NE`

Now need I need the remaining cells up to `LastRow` with:
`Apple_RED_1060`
`Apple_RED_1070`
`Apple_RED_1080`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!  I replaced `With ActiveSheet.Range("G20")` with `With ActiveSheet.Range("G" & y)`, where `y = x + 2`.  Here's my full macro (no need to split it into 2 macros):

```
Sub Set_Tag()

Dim TagName As String
Dim x As Long, y As Long, TagNum As Long, TagNum2 As Long, i As Long, k As Long

TagName = InputBox("What is the product tag name? Ex. Apple", "Tag Name")
TagNum = InputBox("What is the 1st starting tag #?", "1st Tag #")
TagNum2 = InputBox("What is the 2nd starting tag #?", "2nd Tag #")

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("J:J"), " ")
y = x + 2

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    z = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
End With

k = 0
With ActiveSheet.Range("G2")
    For i = 1 To x Step 3
        .Item(i + 0) = TagName & "_" & TagNum + k
        .Item(i + 1) = TagName & "_" & TagNum + k & "_T"
        .Item(i + 2) = TagName & "_" & TagNum + k & "_NE"
        k = k + 10
    Next
End With

k = 0
    With ActiveSheet.Range("G" & y)
    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
        .Item(i + 0) = TagName & "_RED_" & TagNum2 + k
        k = k + 10
    Next
End With

End Sub
```